# How to compare two excel files and replace the matching value in one of the excel file column where the match found using C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I have two excel sheet files say Excel1 and Excel2.
In Excel1, I have two columns as -
COL A and COL B with around 10000 rows data.

In Excel2, I have three columns as -
COL1, COL2 and COL3

From above two excel, COLA(From Excel1) and COL1(Excel2) has the same entries.
Depending on the matching string, I have to copy the COLB value from Excel1 to COL3 of Excel2.

Can anyone please guide me on this, how to do it using C#?

Thanks,

Comment: CSV are NOT excel files

Comment: I have 4 files, 2 excel files and 2 .csv file. So I need to compare both excel file separatly also 2 .csv file as well.

Comment: then Its unclear what you are doing with your csv files

Comment: If you can guide me on how to do with excel , that will be great. have updated it in the question as of now.

Comment: I'm not sure about earlier versions, but if you're using Office 2016, try the Spreadsheet Compare utility that should be located at `Start > Microsoft Office Tools > Spreadsheet Compare`.